# Post data to Google Spreadsheet via AppsScript (private deployment)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, service-accounts

I am trying to post data using HTML forms or AJAX over to AppsScript attached to a Google Spreadsheet. I got the app to the state that it works with app deployed to "anyone, even anonymous".

But my goal is to create JS script or PHP which will use service account to authenticate and post data to this Spreadsheet.

I can't find any helpful documenation or example.

Here is my code: [HTML]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="https://script.google.com/a/macros/domainname/s/AKfycbzVVBWfeffKo7OHdhAtjjgri0ouJ5qIkSjQTpsIISw8/exec">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="test1">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="test2">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

[Apps Script]

```html
function doPost(e) {

  try {
    var doc     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet   = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    
    
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e.parameters));
    
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
  finally {
    return;
  }

}
```

I already created the service account and have the JSON file with clientID, Secrets etc. I imagine I need to append the POST with this data somehow but I am not sure how to achieve that so Google Apps will authenticate it.

The reason for this is that the company who wants this app cannot enable sharing documents to everyone who have the link for security reasons.

I need to publish with settings show below:
[image]

If I set to "Anyone within domain" I get
[image]

So I want to execute my Form somehow so it executes as a user within that domain.

Can someone help with some documentation URLs or some tutorial, etc?

Best Regards
Matt

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use service accounts in this case, even with your restriction.

Publish the app to run as you, then all spreadsheet calls will use your credentials not the user that uses your webapp.

Also, its not possible to use 2-legged oauth with service accounts in apps script, it only supports 3-legged oauth.

Comment: I updated my question. Basically the "who has access to the app" is the factor I need to obey. The GAPS account does not allow to set those settings to "Anyone, even anonymous" or "Anyone" so if I set this the one I have which is "Anyone within domain" then my form hosted on some server does not have access to it. I get "Sorry, unable to open the file at present".

Comment: what do you mean by "hosted on some server". the error you get is either an apps script bug or possibly you gsuite domain has something disabled that GAS needs.

Comment: My form.html is just hosted on apache. The way I want it to work is to send POST data to Google spreadsheet. I have it working fine if the Script is deployed with access to the app "Anyone, even anonymous". The issue is that GAPS which this should work on does not allow to share scripts this way only "Anyone within domain". I am looking for the way to send the POST data as authenticated within this domain.

Comment: aha. but your question now is COMPLETELY  different. you should have clearly explained it on the original question​. and it wont be possible to workarround your issue because your gapps domain​ restrictions your admin put in place.